# maximum possible number of paths in an acyclic digraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have been trying to find a general formula for the maximum possible number of paths in an acyclic digraph.  The method I used was to simply draw several differently sized digraphs with the maximum amount of links, count each path and see if I noticed any patterns.

Here is what I found:

[image]

The pattern I noticed is that the maximum possible paths from "start" to "end" seems to be equal to $ 2^{n-2} $, where n = number of nodes in the digraph.  I was wondering if anyone could possibly explain a more mathematical approach to solving this problem.

Comment: @hbm seems to have supplied a nice proof.  In addition, the bound is achieved by [transitive tournaments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#Transitivity): we draw the vertices along a line, and direct every edge from left-to-right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that every subset of nodes containing start and end gives a path from start to end and vice verse. So, the number of paths is the same as the number of subsets. To get a subset containing start and end just pick any subset that contains neither of those nodes and then add them. That means picking a subset of a set of $n-2$ nodes, but the total number of those subsets is $2^{n-2}$. Thus, the number of paths is  $2^{n-2}$

Answer (score 0):

**1- Finding the Number of Subsets of a Set**

Let's start with stating the obvious: Every path from start to end must contain the start and end nodes and can include as many or as less nodes in between. In other words, its a given that the start and end nodes are included in the path, so we play around with the remaining (N-2) nodes. In set theory lingo that translates to: For a DAG that has N-2 intermediate nodes. Any number of these nodes can be included. How many different paths are possible?

C(N-2, 0) + C(N-2, 1) + C(N-2, 2) + C(N-2, 3) + ....... + C(N-2, N-2)

For simplicity, let n = N-2

C(n, 0) = How many ways we can choose zero intermediate nodes between start and end = n!/(n-k)! * k! = n!/(n! * 0!) = 1
C(n, 1) = How many ways we can choose 1 intermediate nodes between start and end ... etc

Below is a visual illustration of the possible paths for a sample DAG:

[visual explanation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6qRU.jpg)

**2- Children and chairs**

Another way to find the upper limit mathematically is as follows:
For each one of the intermediate nodes (excluding start and end node) there is one of two options: Either be part of the path, or no. This can be expressed as follows: If we have 3 intermediate nodes, we can treat them as chairs.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Wat.jpg) * [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Wat.jpg) * [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Wat.jpg) = 2^3 = 8 paths

[visual description 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Wat.jpg)

K = number of paths = `2^(N-2)`

Time comlexity = `E + k*V = E + 2^(N-2)*V`, where E = number of Edges, V = number of vertices

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math. Thank you.